# FluidSynth not available using scamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following boilerplate code

```
from scamp import *

s = Session()
s.tempo = 120

clarinet = s.new_part("clarinet")
```

When I run it, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/norhther/Descargas/music.py", line 6, in <module>
    clarinet = s.new_part("clarinet")
  File "/home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scamp/instruments.py", line 184, in new_part
    instrument.add_soundfont_playback(preset=preset, soundfont=soundfont, num_channels=num_channels,
  File "/home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scamp/instruments.py", line 984, in add_soundfont_playback
    SoundfontPlaybackImplementation(bank_and_preset=preset, soundfont=soundfont, num_channels=num_channels,
  File "/home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scamp/playback_implementations.py", line 327, in __init__
    SoundfontHost(
  File "/home/norhther/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scamp/_soundfont_host.py", line 176, in __init__
    raise ModuleNotFoundError("FluidSynth not available.")
ModuleNotFoundError: FluidSynth not available.
```

I installed `FluidSynth` in my system (Ubuntu) and I can execute it with no problem. I also used pip install `pyFluidSynth` with `pip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This answer predates OP editing the question; The question indeed contained the quoted phrase.

---

> I also used pip install `fluidsynth` with `pip`

The [`fluidsynth`](https://pypi.org/project/fluidsynth/) package on PyPI was last updated in 2012, and is not what SCAMP depends on for interfacing with FluidSynth. The correct package to be installed is called [`pyFluidSynth`](https://pypi.org/project/pyFluidSynth/). To install it, run the following command.

```bash
pip install pyFluidSynth
```

You'll also have to uninstall the wrong `fluidsynth` package.

```bash
pip uninstall fluidsynth
```

Comment: I already have this package installed, same error

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should also remove the wrong package. I updated the answer with instructions to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I fixed the error.
On the official Scamp docs, they say:
"On the new Apple Silicon Macs, the bundled intel-based copy of FluidSynth will not work. I’m working on bundling a version that will work, but in the meantime, you can install FluidSynth via Homebrew. Simply install homebrew via the script on the website, and then run brew install fluid-synth from a terminal."